# Are smooth specializations of smooth hypersurfaces again hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hypersurfaces

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth projective hypersurface of degree $d$ (over the complex numbers).

Assume $n$ is very large compared to $d$, and that $d$ is a prime number (e.g., $d=3$ and $n > 1000000000$). In particular, $X$ is a Fano variety (of dimension $n-1$ and Picard rank $1$).

Let $X_0$ be a smooth projective specialization of $X$. Then $X_0$ is also a Fano variety. However, as far as I can tell, it could happen that $X_0$ is not a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$. When does this actually happen?

Just to be clear: here we say that $X$ specializes to $X_0$ if there is a smooth proper morphism of schemes $\mathcal{X}\to \mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{C}[[t]]$ whose generic fibre is $X_{\mathbb{C}((t))}$ and whose special fibre is $X_0$.

Comment: For $d$ equal to $2$, I believe this is the Ph.D. thesis of Jun-Muk Hwang.  For higher $d$, I would first check the articles of Hwang and Mok: they prove many such results for other Fano manifolds (most famously, the irreducible Hermitian symmetric spaces of compact type).

Comment: Hwang's result mentioned by Jason appeared in Inventiones. I doubt very much that the case of cubic hypersurfaces is known.

Comment: I think the case of cubic hypersurfaces of dimension at least 3 follows from [Fujita, Classification theories of polarized varieties, Chapter I, (6.7)] applied to a smooth specialization of such cubics. The assumptions that Fujita makes in [loc. cit., (6.2)] hold by [loc. cit. (6.1.1) and (6.1.2)].

Comment: And the case of quintic hypersurfaces and septic threefolds is now a theorem of Ottem and Schreieder: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.12711.